# split line using delimiter and store both fields in a different variable

Tags: shell-script, cut

I have a text file having multiple rows. I am using the while command to read the file line-wise but I need to store the values in separate variables and use them in the trailing shell-script.

The **cut** command delimits the complete file not the read line.

Example `my_file.txt`:

```
d1:jobid1
id2:jobid2
```

I am using the below while loop to read the file line-wise

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    jobid=`cut -d: -f2`
    id=`cut -d: -f1`

#remaining shell-script dependent upon variables#

done < my_file.txt
```

I want to store the jobid and id for every line in `my_file.txt` and run the trailing script. **Each line is in a new line**

Need help to store the values in the variables recursively. If there is a better way to read line wise and delimit and store the two fields separately.

Answer (score 6):

`cut` reads from standard input by default. In your command substitution, standard input is inherited from the loop's standard input (since you provide no other explicit input for the calls to `cut`).  The loop's standard input comes from your input file.

The effect becomes that the first line of your file is read by `read`, while all other lines are read by the very first call to `cut`. The value in the `jobid` variable would therefore be a new-line delimited string of job IDs while the `id` variable would be empty. The loop would run a single iteration only.

You *could use*, for example,

```
id=$( printf '%s\n' "$line" | cut -d: -f1 )

# or: id=$( cut -d: -f1 <<<"$line" )
# (in shells that supports "here-strings")
```

but that would be unnecessary as it would be cleaner and much more efficient to do

```bash
while IFS=: read -r id jobid; do
    # code that uses "$id" and "$jobid" goes here
done <my_file.txt
```

This uses the fact that `read` can read data from a line of input into multiple variables at once.  By setting `IFS` to a colon, the line is split on the colon and the first field is read into `id` while the rest is read into `jobid`.  There is no need to call `cut` at all.